# Deserialising RouteXL Response In Java using Gson Difficult as RouteXL Returns Multiple Objects Rather Than Array

Tags: java, json, rest, api, gson

I'm trying to deserialize the response from RouteXL using **`Java`** & `GSON`, however, the routes come back as separate objects, and not an array which is a pain.  Does anyone know an easy way of deserializing the response from `RouteXL API1`?  Sadly API2 does the same.

**Json Response:**

```
{
  "id": "xJFPS2Z3",
  "count": 4,
  "feasible": true,
  "route": {
    "0": {
      "name": "11 Main Street",
      "arrival": 0,
      "distance": 0
    },
    "1": {
      "name": "19 Slate Road",
      "arrival": 10,
      "distance": 9.3
    },
    "2": {
      "name": "234 Woodland Road",
      "arrival": 18,
      "distance": 14.5
    },
    "3": {
      "name": "15 Great Eastern Road",
      "arrival": 29,
      "distance": 26.4
    }
  }
}
```

Its almost like you need to create a class like this to hold all the responses:

```java
public class Route {
    private Waypoint 1;
    private Waypoint 2;
    private Waypoint 3;
    private Waypoint 4;
    private Waypoint 5;
    ...

    public Route(Waypoint 1, Waypoint 2, Waypoint 3, Waypoint 4, Waypoint 5) {
        this.1 = 1;
        this.1 = 2;
        this.3 = 3;
        this.4 = 4;
        this.5 = 5;
    }
}
```

Which isn't valid java as the variable cannot be a number.

**I've tried** using sites such as [json schema 2 pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) and [pojo sodhana library](http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com) but they pretty much do what I have done.

I'm pretty new to JSON and Rest API's so apologies if obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead `Route` class in root object use `Map`:

```
private Map<String, Waypoint> route;
```

Comment: Perfect that works and very quick response. Thanks Michal.